# What is the difference between 'como' and 'cómo'?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, definiciones

Is there a difference between 'como' and 'cómo'? I'm confused. It's supposed to be two different words, right? Where do I draw the line?

When I look up [how](https://en.pons.com/translate?q=how&l=enes&in=ac_en&lf=es) it says that it's both 'como' and 'cómo'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79188/discussion-on-question-by-user3510079-what-is-the-difference-between-como-and).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually a good bit more than two words, but it's easiest to think when to use the accent then when not to.

- *como* (no accent) can be used as a verb (from *comer*), noun (dated word meaning a *trick*), adverb, conjunction, or preposition.
- *cómo* (accent) can mean either the interrogative/relative pronoun *how?* (¿Cómo estás?  No sé cómo lo haces.) or can be used to express incredulity where English uses *what?* (¿Cómo?).  The moment you hear yourself giving a questioning intonation, you'll accent it.

There is a well known phrase, *¿Cómo como?  Como como como.* which uses three of these.  The first is the question *How?*, the second, third, and fifth are the verb *I eat*, and the fourth is *like/as*.  So... *How do I eat?  I eat like I eat*.

But you can extend it further adding in the incredulous *cómo* and get *¿Cómo cómo como?  Como como como.* to mean "What do you mean how do I eat?! I eat like I eat."

Comment: @jabujavi please do not edit my post with incorrect information.  Como is a preposition per the DRAE "Como. 13. ***prep***. en calidad de. *Asiste a la boda como testigo*."

Answer (score 2):

- 'Cómo': how. It is often used to make questions
- 'Como': as, like, such as.

So you would say:

> Eres tan bueno como él <sub>You are as good as him.</sub>
>
> Es como un gran monstruo <sub>It is like a big monster</sub>
>
> Eres como un genio <sub>You are such as a genious</sub>

Answer (score 1):

¿Cómo como?  ¡Como como como! <sub>How do I eat?  I eat the way I eat!</sub>

- The first como (the one with the accent) is the word "how", introducing a question.
- The second como is "I eat".
- So is the third and fifth one.
- The fourth como is "the way".  It is like the first one except that it's used in an indication, while the first one is used to introduce a question.

I heard this as a sort of light hearted joke in SA.

Answer (score 0):

- (Yo) 'como' = I eat
- 'Cómo' = how

The accent mark tells you whether it's referring to the verb 'comer' or the auxiliar 'how'.

Examples:

> Siempre **como** en casa antes de ir al colegio <sub>I always eat at home before going to school</sub>
>
> ¿**Cómo** estás? <sub>How are you?</sub>

Comment: Esta respuesta deja fuera otras funciones/tipos de "como" sin acento, por ejemplo "Me siento **como** en casa". "Como" no es sólo la primera persona de presente de indicativo de _Comer_.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón

Answer (score -1):

- '(Yo) Como' = I eat

It comes from the verb 'comer'. It is the 'yo' form present tense.

- 'Cómo' = How

Sometimes when people want to say *how* in Spanish, they can say 'Cómo'. One expression that has 'cómo' is:

> ¿Cómo estás? <sub>How are you?</sub>