# ¿Debo tildar "cuando" o no?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, adverbios

En esta pregunta no tengo claro si "cuando" lleva tilde o no.

Pregunta:

- ¿Qué sientes cuando tu bebé te dice mamá?
- ¿Qué sientes cuándo tu bebé te dice mamá?

Yo creo que lleva tilde ¿por ser una conjunción o no?

Comment: Pregunta relacionada [“Muéstrame cómo hiciste” o “Muéstrame como hiciste”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19868/5481) y [What is the difference between 'como' and 'cómo'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12251/5481), que viene a ser lo mismo pero con "como" en lugar de "cuando"

Answer (score 3):

Debe escribirse sin tilde, porque es una conjunción o [adverbio relativo](https://www.rae.es/dpd/cuando). Introduce una oración subordinada que indica el tiempo en el que ocurre la acción.

El adverbio interrogativo [cuándo](https://www.rae.es/dpd/cu%C3%A1ndo), con tilde, se usa en preguntas cuya respuesta es el tiempo en el que ocurre la acción. El adverbio con tilde *sustituye* a la expresión temporal, mientras que el adverbio sin tilde la *introduce*. Por tanto,

- ¿Qué sientes cuando tu bebé te dice "mamá"?

se escribe sin tilde, mientras que

- ¿Sabes cuándo tu bebé te dijo "mamá" por primera vez?

se escribe con tilde.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, gracias.

Comment: @wimi En este caso, cabe aclarar que es conjunción. Sería adverbio relativo si antes hubiera un sustantivo, por ejemplo: *El **día cuando** tu bebé te diga mamá será inolvidable.*

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas en tu pregunta, qué va acentuado, lleva tilde, luego te pregunto, por qué lleva tilde qué? porque es un pronombre interrogativo, qué sustituye a lo que sientes. Entonces te pregunto cuándo es como qué, sustituye a algo? no, introduce un complemento circunstancial que es una subordinada, sin embargo qué no introduce ninguna subordinada, no son iguales, luego no lleva acento o tilde.